# How to render ReactJS with component name and its props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Working version**

```
// Load from defined component
const TextField = require('textfield');

render: function() {
  <div>
   <TextField label='sample' defaultValue='default' placeholder='type your value' />
  </div>
}
```

**Improved version, but not working**

And then I have so many TextField, so I refactor my code to create the props in a more generic way. Then, I expect kind of things like this will work, but it won't:

```
render: function() {
  <div>
   // This not working but raised error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys: {label, defaultValue, placeholder}
   React.createElement(TextField, this._getPropsForField('sample'))
  </div>
},

_getPropsForField: function(fieldName) {
  // Initialize data for fieldName, but return a mock for now
  return {
    label: 'sample',
    defaultValue: 'default',
    placeholder: 'placeholder'
  };
}
```

I also tried:

```
TextField(this._getPropsForField())
```

But it didn't work with the same error.

I appreciate any help or suggestion, thank you guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a whole set of props using the spread operator, which has a kind of special use case in JSX.

```
<TextField { ...(_getPropsForField('field')) } />
```

**[Example](http://www.webpackbin.com/4JhdlewGZ)**

Comment: Yes, `...` does the magic! Any other options to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Going full JSX is better, but this line:

```
React.createElement(TextField, this._getPropsForField('sample'))
```

You are missing the `{ }` brackets to escape JSX. With them it should work also:

```
{React.createElement(TextField, this._getPropsForField('sample'))}
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be rendered as a string instead of giving an error in the case the `{}`s are missing?

Comment: Yes it should. But the string would not raise the error :) I guess the original code that raised the error was different than in your question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know JSX much but I think you can't put `React.createElement(TextField, {})` inside `<div>` (as @wintvelt points out, you have to wrap it inside a `{}`). So I would use pure JS like this:

```
render: function() {
  textField = React.createElement(TextField, this._getPropsForField('sample'));

  return React.createElement('div', null, textField);
  // Or this shortcut:
  return React.DOM.div(null, textField);
},
```

Or with pretty CoffeeScript:

```
render: ->
  React.DOM.div
    null
    React.createElement TextField, @_getPropsForField('sample')
```

Comment: If you put it in {} brackets, you can actually put it inside JSX. JSX code actually compiles to `React.createElement()`.